# TCL/TK How do I pass multiple arguments to a button call back function?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a code like this

```
  proc press2 {v sbit} {
                puts $v
                puts $sbit
        }

                   :
                   :
button .t.ok2 -text "OKI" -command "press2 $v $sbit"
```

with this I get the error `wrong # args: should be "press2 v sbit"` 
if I change it to  `button .t.ok2 -text "OKI" -command {press2 $v $sbit}` I get `can't read "v": no such variable` and finally I tried `button .t.ok2 -text "OKI" -command [press2 $v $sbit]` which doesn't give any errors but doesn't work also. Just asking is there any good documentation available for TCL/TK ? The usual man pages and googling isnt helping me much. I am doing much by trial and error.

Comment: It should be working with braces. But do the variables `$v` and `$sbit` exist? (Alternatively, you can use `-command "press2 \$v \$sbit"`)

Comment: No its not working yes the variables exist because if I pass $v alone it tends to work.

Comment: Well, it's working fine here. I get the error `can't read "v" ...` only if `$v` doesn't exist. Also, what do you mean "tends" to work? It sounds fishy.

Comment: ha seems like it was a mistake.. v is a variable that is not defined in this window.. the code is something like this proc foo(){ set v 100... then I create a new toplevel window and in that window I've a button and that button calls a proc with 'v' as one of its arguments which gives error.. I tried replacing 'v' with the variables present in the same window and then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Passing multiple arguments to a procedure is easy, but the "correct" way depends on what you want:

- **Early Binding**: If you want to pass the current values later (e.g. if you create the widgets in a loop) you need to use [`list`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/list.htm):

  ```
  button .t.ok2 -text OKI -command [list press2 $v $sbit]
  ```

  [`list`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/list.htm) creates a command that is free from any further substitution*.
- **Late Binding**: If you want pass the value when this command is executed, simply brace it with `{}`

  ```
  button .t.ok2 -text OKI -command {press2 $v $sbit}
  ```

  The variables `v` and `sbit` are subsituted when the button is pressed. You only have access to global variables (or variables in a namespace, but not local variables).

<sub>* Tk's `bind` replaces `%` and a following character with something special. This is done using string substitution, not Tcl substitution, so `list` does not guard against this.</sub>

Comment: Btw: The documentation is excelent. If you understand that you have to pass a string that is evaluated later (in an other scope), you'll find yourself in the situation that you need to pass something without further substitution. `list` does exactly this.

Comment: Also, if you're wanting to mix early and late binding (i.e., `[list …]` and `{…}`) then you're making things too complicated. Adding a helper procedure — it should take the early-bound values as arguments and does the late binding when called — will make everything _far easier to understand_ than anything else.